# Showing that a function is always between two other functions by differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is differentiable and $1 \leq f'(x) \leq 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f(0) = 0$ then $x \leq f(x) \leq 2x $ for $x \geq0$.

Here is my attempted proof:

1. Since $f$ is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , there is a theorem that states: If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=c \in D$ where $D$ is some domain, then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$
2. Since $f$ differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ must also be continuous $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by statement $1$.
3. Since $f$ is continuous and defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $D \subset \mathbb{R}$, suppose that there exists some $c \in D $ where $c$ is a local extreme point for $f$. Then exactly one of the the following assertions hold: $(1)$ $c$ is an endpoint of the interval $D$, $(2)$ $c$ is an interior point of $D$ but $f'(c)$ fails to exist, or $(3)$ $c$ is an interior point of $D$ and $f'(c) = 0$.
4. In the case of this question, assertions $(2)$ and $(3)$ do not hold up, so $c$ must be an endpoint of the interval $D$.
5. This implys that $c$, the local maximum or minimum of $f$, occurs at its endpoints and since $x \leq f(x) \leq 2x $ $f$ must be between, or equalt to $x$ or $2x$.

I would love some feedback to see if this adequately answers the question, and if not, where the flaws in my logic are. I feel like I'm not adequately connecting ideas.

Comment: Use the Mean Value Theorem. Two separate arguments, $x\le f(x)$ and $f(x)\le 2x$. For the first, $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$,  But $f'(c)\ge 1$, and we are basically finished proving the first inequality. Or equivalently let $G(x)=f(x)-x$. We find that $G(x)$ is non-decreasing by looking at the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Mean value theorem is probably the best way to do it as stated above. That is to say, for any x, we have $f$ differentiable on $[0,x]$. It follows that there is a $c\in (0,x)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} &= f'(c)\\
1 \leq &f'(c)\leq 2\\
\Rightarrow 1\leq &\frac{f(x) - 0}{x} \leq 2\\
x\leq &f(x) \leq 2x
\end{align*}
Another way to do it is via the fundamental theorem of calculus.
\begin{align*}
f(x) -f(0) &= \int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt\\
f(x) &=\int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt \\
1\leq f'(t) \leq 2 &\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x}1 \leq \int_{0}^{x} f'(t)dt \leq\int_{0}^{x} 2dt\\
x\leq f(x) \leq 2x
\end{align*}